# Match and copy cell in worksheet to corresponding tab

Tags: vba, macros

I receive a form like LTest from every sales order, I would like to copy certain data from LTest and copy it into 2016 Test 1. Each form is formatted the same and I want to use the data in cell B3 of LTest to select to proper tab in 2016 Test 1 and then insert the information in the corresponding cells of that same worksheet. The name of LTest will vary from one order to another and I will have to tweak the form to include an order number that will also be unique.

One issues is LTest and 2016 Test 1 are different spreadsheets.

```
Sub Keysha_Bee()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SheetID As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Integer

Set wb1 = Workbooks("LTest")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks("2016 Test1")

If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "FPPI") > 0 Then SheetID = "FPPI-Routed"
If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "USPPI") > 0 Then SheetID = "USPPI-Routed"
If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "Standard") > 0 Then SheetID = "Standard"

i = 1

Do Until i > wb2.Sheets.Count
    If wb2.Sheets(i).Name = SheetID Then Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(i) Else GoTo Nexti
    lrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 2) = ws1.Range("D6") 'Customer Name
    If ws2.Range("D14") = "" Then
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 3) = ws1.Range("D17") 'Agent's Name
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 4) = ws1.Range("D18") 'Auth Agent's Email
    Else
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 3) = ws1.Range("D15") 'Agent's Name
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 4) = ws1.Range("D16") 'Auth Agent's Email
    End If
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 5) = "NO" 'Routed, not sure what this is supposed to reference
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 6) = ws1.Range("D20") ' Routed
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 7) = ws1.Range("D26") ' Origin
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 8) = ws1.Range("D27") ' Hazardous
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 9) = ws1.Range("D28") ' UC Type
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 10) = "Date" 'Not sure what this is supposed to refference

Nexti:
i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with your code?  What is it doing or not doing that you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (EDITED):

```
Sub Keysha_Bee()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim SheetID As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Integer

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook '<<edited
    'get the "other open workbook" (must have only the 2 open!)
    For Each wb In Application.WorkBooks
        If wb.Name <> wb2.Name then
            Set wb1 = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
    If wb1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No other workbook open!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)

    If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "FPPI") > 0 Then SheetID = "FPPI-Routed"
    If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "USPPI") > 0 Then SheetID = "USPPI-Routed"
    If InStr(ws1.Range("B3"), "Standard") > 0 Then SheetID = "Standard"

    On Error Resume Next 'ignore any error
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(SheetID)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors

    'was ws2 set ?
    If ws2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & SheetID & "' was not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lrow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 2) = ws1.Range("D6") 'Customer Name
    If ws2.Range("D14") = "" Then
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 3) = ws1.Range("D17") 'Agent's Name
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 4) = ws1.Range("D18") 'Auth Agent's Email
    Else
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 3) = ws1.Range("D15") 'Agent's Name
        ws2.Cells(lrow, 4) = ws1.Range("D16") 'Auth Agent's Email
    End If
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 5) = "NO" 'Routed, not sure what this is supposed to reference
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 6) = ws1.Range("D20") ' Routed
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 7) = ws1.Range("D26") ' Origin
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 8) = ws1.Range("D27") ' Hazardous
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 9) = ws1.Range("D28") ' UC Type
    ws2.Cells(lrow, 10) = "Date" 'Not sure what this is supposed to refference

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I am getting hung up at     Set wb1 = Workbooks("LTest")  - I'm not sure why it is getting caught there because I have both workbooks open.

Comment: Also, I named this workbook L Test for this conversation but the name of the workbook will vary once this is functioning properly. How to I address that?

Comment: Need something more descriptive than "hung up"  Try `Set wb1 = Workbooks("LTest.xlsx")`  - or whatever the actual extension is.

Comment: *How* will the name vary?  If you need to be able to use a random file then you can use `Application.getOpenFilename` to pick one (as long as it's closed) and then open it.  Where is your code - is it in "2016 Test1" ?  If Yes then you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead of having to use the name.

Comment: yes, you are correct in that the file names will vary. the code is in 2016 Test1

Comment: Then you can use `ThisWorkbook` in place of `wb2`

Comment: See my edits above, to switch `wb2` to `ThisWorkbook`, and to use whatever other workbook is open in excel when you run the macro as `wb1`